# mysql_affect_rows is done by DDL or DML?

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl, dml

Today, my senior asked me a mysql_query to get number of affected rows, I said that’s very easy “mysql_affected_rows”, but suddenly he asked by which it is done, by using DDL or by DML?
I have never heard that a query is DDL or DML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are `D`ata `D`efinition `L`anguage and `D`ata `M`anipulation `L`anguage. Google is your friend. Example of DDL is `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: But as I found on the internet is reverse. 

On this page, http://www.orafaq.com/faq/what_are_the_difference_between_ddl_dml_and_dcl_commands

It says, DDL is used in CREATE, ALTER, DROP, TRUNCATE, COMMENT, RENAME. All these functions are changing the database structure and schema. But getting mysql_affected_rows is not changing the database schema. Then how it could be DDL ?

Comment: I don't see any contradiction. I show you example of DDL, but didn't said, that an answer for your question is `DDL`. And you're right with those search result. Answer to question from your senior is `DML`.